# AutoCompleteTextView Item selection trigger event

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-textinputlayout, onitemselectedlistener

I want an error on TextInputLayout to be disabled when an item is selected from `AutoCompleteTextView`

This is googles documentation on AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

In my fragment `onCreateView` method i have

```java
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_currency_picker, container, false);

TextInputLayout mtextInputLayout= view.findViewById(R.id.currencyTIL);

List<String> currenciesAvailable = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currencies_array));

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.dropdown_currency_item, currenciesAvailable);

AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = view.findViewById(R.id.AutoCompTxtView);
    
autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);

autoComplete.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

In my fragment I've also implemented

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Log.d("TEST", "XYZ");
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

I can't seem to trigger onItemSelected. Ultimately I want to call

mtextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on an item on the adapter it is not a Selection but a click event

use this to remove the Error when the items are clicked by adding `mtextInputLayout.setError(null)` on the click listener:

```java
autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mtextInputLayout.setError(null);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the **`setOnItemClickListener`** listener:

```
autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        //do something...
    }
});
```

Since you are using a Material Component Theme the `AutoCompleteTextView` is replaced at runtime by the `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView`.

As you can check in the [code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.3.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.java#L122) when an item in the Popup is selected the `OnItemClickListener` interface is called.